# Obfuscator for .NET Core

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Is there any software that can obfuscate .NET Core assembly? Open source and Commerical are accepted

Answer (score 8):

[Obfuscar](https://www.obfuscar.com/) is a .NET assemblies obfuscation tool that should do it without problems. You can install it from Nuget (it's available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Obfuscar/)).
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Source code of Obfuscar is on https://github.com/obfuscar. Runs on .NET Standard, .NET Core, framework, unity and xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

if you have not found the answer I can advise to try [ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/). It uses virtual machine to obfuscate the code.
Good luck!

Comment: Could you add some description of what it does and at least a link for downloading?

Comment: Of course! I work with this tool not for long. As I understood the virtual machine is used for obfuscation. Info from official site: " ArmDot has a proven approach that is widely used for the unmanaged code: the original code is converted into an array of bytes that is interpreted by special virtual machine. Each time you apply ArmDot, it creates a new version of virtual machine and uses a new set of instructions to represent the original code."
https://www.armdot.com/
I hope this will be usefu

Answer (score 1):

[Skater](http://rustemsoft.com/obfuscator.asp) .NET Obfuscator ver8.7 protects .NET Core dlls.

Comment: download link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rustemsoft.SkaterNETFreeObfuscator

Answer (score 1):

[Babel](https://www.babelfor.net/) Obfuscator can obfuscate .NET Core 3.0 with code virtualization.

Comment: Welcome!  Please update your question with a link, and provide the cost (if any) of the software.  Also, if there are other helpful details to include, please do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reactor](https://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm) offers obfuscation support (including code virtualization and code encryption) for .NET Core 2.x and 3.x. Furthermore you can bundle your whole .NET Core project into a single executable file.